# Why can I only use apt-get when I use "su"?

Tags: apt, sudo, environment-variables, su, http-proxy

Not sure what info you need here, if any. Just let me know.  I have a proxy that bypasses the corporate net set in my profile file for both su and normal user.  When I do a sudo or regular apt-get install as a normal user, it hangs as if it can't communicate out, I have inter-web access though.  When I do the same apt-get as a su, it works, no problem. What you think ?

Comment: Interesting. My first guess is that sudo is not grabbing the full login profile of root, and therefore does not pickup the proper proxy configuration. When you su and apt-get as separate operations it works, however? Here are some other things to try:
'su' vs 'su -': is there a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be related with environment variables.

If you set the proxy in your profile (as environment variables), then probably when issuing `sudo`, these variables don't get loaded.

If you succeed doing so with `su`, then probably you're using `su -` (that's the way to load the environment variables of `root`).

To get loaded these variables (for a normal user) —if my assumptions are right— you should use the option `-E` of `sudo`. You should see the manual of `sudo` for further details.

Comment: no sure what 'su -' is would I be explicitly typing that into command line ?

Comment: Aren't you issuing `su -`? If you are using just `su`, then I don't know why `apt-get` *knows* the proxy environment variable. How did you setup the proxy?

Comment: I am changing user to su, then doing apt-get install XXX

Comment: What is the syntaxis you're using to set the proxy?

Comment: export http_proxy, HTTP_PROXY, etc...

Comment: Try doing `sudo -E apt-get install ...` and tell us what happens.

Comment: yes that works! What does '-E' do ?